# How remove item from list getting from state?

Tags: redux, dart, flutter

I'm using flutter redux for my state management.
But whenever I remove the item from a list using `removeAt()` in reducer, it always removes the last item of that list.

State:

```
class TimeTableState {
 final List<TimeTableModel> items;  
 TimeTableState({@required this.items});
 TimeTableState.initialState(): items = <TimeTableModel>[];
}
```

Action:

```
class DeleteAction {
 final TimeTableModel model;
 final int index;
 DeleteAction({@required this.model, @required this.index});
}
```

Reducer:

```
else if(action is DeleteAction) {
  state.items.removeAt(action.index);
  return TimeTableState(
    items: state.items
  );
}
```

Widget:

```
new StoreConnector<TimeTableState, ViewModel>(
 converter: (store) => new ViewModel.delete(
 deleteAction: (model, index) => 
  store.dispatch(DeleteAction(model: model, index: index))
 ),
 builder: (cxt, view) => 
   new Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
     new IconButton(
     onPressed: () {
      view.deleteAction(viewModel[widget.index], widget.index);
     },
     icon: new Icon(Icons.delete),
     iconSize: 25.0,
     color: Colors.amber,
     )
    ],
   ),
  )
```

Comment: Please add the code required to reproduce.

Comment: I have updated with code

Comment: What is printed when you add `print('length: ${state.items.length}, index: ${action.index}');` just before `state.items.removeAt(action.index);`

Comment: When the list of an item of 2 and removing the first item it shows length: 2, index: 0

Comment: Do you have `reverse: true` in your list widget?

Comment: I'm using sliver list builder with expansion tile as a child

Comment: You can set a breakpoint at `state.items.removeAt(action.index);` and investigate `state.items` before and after you execute that line. I'm sure it will remove the item at index 0. If that is not reflected in your view, I can't tell why from the code in your question.